# Sorting An ArrayList of Objects by Object Parameters - Integers

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have This method below which works for sorting out Student objects in an arraylist using String parameters, for example a Student Object would have a String name,int age and String course parameter

```
//This Sorts with String parameters
public void sortArrayListByName()
{
    Collections.sort(sList,new Comparator<Student>() {
         public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
                 return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
         }
     });
}
```

Now I want to implement this code with integer parameters

```
//This should sort the Arraylist of Objects
public void sortArrayListByAge()
{
    Collections.sort(sList,new Comparator<Student>() {
         public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
                 return s1.getAge().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getAge()); //This Part gives me errors
         }
     });
}
```

But i get an error message saying **Cannot invoke compareToIgnoreCase(int) on the primitive type int**

How can i fix this code so that it will be able to sort the list with integer values?

Comment: If age in the `Student` class is of type `int` then just use a simple equality comparison operator.

Comment: `int`s **are not** `String`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing `int` values, which are primitive types and `int` does not have any methods. This is why `s1.getAge().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getAge())` fails.

If you happen to use Java 7 or prior, use [`Integer#compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-):

```
public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
    return Integer.compare(s1.getAge(), s2.getAge()); 
}
```

Otherwise, compare the `int` variables manually (code adapted from `Integer#compare` source, there's no need to reinvent the wheel):

```
public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
    return (s1.getAge() < s2.getAge()) ? -1 : ((s1.getAge() == s2.getAge()) ? 0 : 1); 
}
```

Comment: haha yea, this works, i don't know why i didn't think of that, thanks for your input

Comment: Take care to check for `null` on either of your objects or this solution could break.

Comment: @RyanJ if there's a NPE I would not worry on this method but why I added null elements in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//This should sort the Arraylist of Objects
public void sortArrayListByAge()
{
    Collections.sort(sList,new Comparator<Student>() {
         public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
                 int result = 0;   // assume equal
                 if ( (s1 == null && s2 != null )|| (s1.getAge() > s2.getAge()) ) {
                     result = 1;
                 }
                 if ( (s1 != null && s2 == null) || s1.getAge() < s2.getAge() ) {
                     result = -1;
                 }
                 return result;
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You already got your answer, but one of the options is to also use `sorted` method from Java 8 Stream API:

```
sList.stream().sorted((s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.getAge(), s2.getAge()))
              .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getName() + ", " + s.getAge()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal comparison operators :

```
public void sortArrayListByAge()
{
    Collections.sort(sList,new Comparator<Student>() {
         public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
                 if (s1 != null && s2 != null) {
                    if (s1.getAge() < s2.getAge())
                        return -1;
                    else {
                        if (s1.getAge() > s2.getAge())
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    }
                 } else if (s1 != null) {
                    return 1; // s2 is null
                 } else if (s2 != null) {
                    return -1; // s1 is null
                 } else {
                    return 0; // both s1 and s2 are null
                 }
         }
     });
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way? (I think you mixed up negative and positive returns.)

Comment: @Jashaszun `a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.` - I think I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

The `compareTo` and `compareToIgnoreCase` methods are inverted.

To sort integers, like age, use:

```
return s1.getAge().compareTo(s2.getAge());
```

And to sort Strings, like names, and ignoring the case, use:

```
return s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());
```